# Одинаковые значения в массиве

Tags: php

Есть массив товаров в корзине.

Если вывести массив получается вот что

```
Array ( 
[02db2e33f6361f61182f0226bff9796b] => Array ( [rowid] => 02db2e33f6361f61182f0226bff9796b [id] => 349 [qty] => 1 [price] => 14000 [name] => Dailies Total 1 [images] => e0cf9568ddbf6c809e4f79d13fdedadc.jpg [discount] => 0 [options] => Array ( [optical] => -01.00 [radius] => 8.5 [optical_power] => [os_grad] => [color] => ) [subtotal] => 14000 ) 
[0ac30b646b9d132a26080046573a91ee] => Array ( [rowid] => 0ac30b646b9d132a26080046573a91ee [id] => 349 [qty] => 1 [price] => 14000 [name] => Dailies Total 1 [images] => e0cf9568ddbf6c809e4f79d13fdedadc.jpg [discount] => 0 [options] => Array ( [optical] => -01.25 [radius] => 8.5 [optical_power] => [os_grad] => [color] => ) [subtotal] => 14000 ) 
[1482d85f3864ac22acea2a7b326d72a5] => Array ( [rowid] => 1482d85f3864ac22acea2a7b326d72a5 [id] => 13 [qty] => 1 [price] => 4580 [name] => ACUVUE 2 6шт. [images] => 00fe0b832ea22485b52523b853503682.jpeg [discount] => 0 [options] => Array ( [optical] => -00.50 [radius] => 8.3 [optical_power] => [os_grad] => [color] => ) [subtotal] => 4580 ) 
)
```

Тут три товара. У двух товаров поле id одинаковое. Мне нужно перебрать весь массив и если одинаковые id то присвоить поле discount=5.

Как сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверняка не лучшее решение, но вот что получилось

```
// Временный массив. Записываем туда шифр товара и id
$temp = array();

// Перебираем массив товаров. На один id может быть несколько товаров. Складываем их
foreach ($items as $item => $fields) {

    $temp[$items[$item]["id"]][] = $item;
}

// Перебираем временный массив.
foreach ($temp as $id => $tempItems) {

    // Если товаров с одинаковым id больше одного, то меняем discount
    if (count($temp[$id]) > 1) {

        foreach ($tempItems as $tempItem) {

            $items[$tempItem]["discount"] = 5;
        }
    }
}
```

[Результат работы](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3b562585bf9527b5994ab56452fea572e13e1ea3). Вроде как вы хотели.